# jquery sortable update

Tags: jquery, sortable

Стоит sortable на таблицу:

```js
$("#abc tbody").sortable({
  helper: fixHelper,
  update: function (event, ui) {
   var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
   $.get('/itemssort.php', {order:newOrder});
  }
});
```

И есть функция для элемента tr:

```js
function toTop(that) {
 var current = $(that).closest('tr');
 var tbody = $(that).parent().find('tr').first();
    current.insertBefore(tbody);
    $('#abc tbody').trigger('update');
}
```

Как после вызова toTop запускать update у sortable?  $('#abc tbody').trigger('update'); не работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `sortupdate` должно работать:

```
$("#abc tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelper
}).on('sortupdate', function () {
    var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    $.get('/itemssort.php', {order:newOrder});
});

$("#abc tbody").trigger('sortupdate');
```